# Exception in retrieving password

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

When I am trying to log-in to my application I am getting the following error message :

```
Mar 13, 2014 11:56:56 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm getPassword
SEVERE: Exception retrieving password for username
```

some configuration:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
          global="jdbc/ARAIDB" 
          maxActive="100" 
          maxIdle="30" 
          maxWait="10000" 
          name="jdbc/ARAIDB" 
          password="" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/arai_prod" 
          username="root"/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm"
       dataSourceName="jdbc/ARAIDB" 
       roleNameCol="role_name" 
       userCredCol="password" 
       userNameCol="account_name"
       userRoleTable="accounts_role"
       userTable="active_account"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in addition to the code, let us know how your tables look like (e.g. active_account and accounts_role) - also, are there other log messages earlier?

Comment: Exactly where did you place the configuration you quoted above?

Comment: I had this problem in Tomcat7, turns out I had wrong userNameCol in DataSourceRealm context.xml config. Double check table and column names in a xml file.